# how to make tic tac toe with AI in javascript with depth-limited algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

i was searching how to make tic tac toe with AI in javascript with depth-limited algorithm and all i've found is the minimax algorithm is that the same as depth limited?

Answer (score 0):

A depth-limited algorithm is one that investigates a fixed number of moves ahead, without necessarily reaching final positions, where the game result is decided. In order to run a depth-limited search, a *heuristic* needs to be defined such that, given an arbitrary position, it can evaluate which player has an advantage.

Minimax can be depth-limited (when using it for complex games it is necessary to limit the depth of the search), however, the *game tree* for tic-tac-toe is quite small, thus in this case it is also feasible to run minimax without the depth limitation.